# Can "boast" take a gerund directly as its object?

Tags: gerunds

Searching the internet to know whether it's grammatically correct to use **"boast"** with a gerund as its direct object, I just came across this sentence in a book

> For one thing, not many towns can boast having a volcano in their
>   backyard. [SOURCE](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=oMaskNdh6NgC&pg=PT250&dq=%22boast%20having%22&hl=ko&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22boast%20having%22&f=false)

I've googled the writer's name and found out that she is an English native speaker and It doesn't seem like she made a mistake, because I found some sentences in which **"boast"** is used in the same way as well by other English writers.

So, my question is...

**Is it really grammatically correct to use "boast" in that way? 
Should there be added a preposition such as "of or about"?**

I'd think **"boast"** or **"boast of or about"** are all correct to use there but the meanings are totally different like

1. For one thing, not many towns can boast having a volcano in their backyard

**"having a volcano in their backyard"** can represents, as a whole, the symbol of not many towns' pride.

2. For one thing, not many towns can boast of or about having a volcano in their backyard

**"having a volcano in their backyard"** can be talked of or about proudly by not many towns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Boast* in that case is a simple transitive verb that acts directly on an object.

> **boast** *v.tr.*
>   2. To have or possess (a desirable feature): *a mall that boasts 80 shops*.
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/boast)</sub>

So yes, it's grammatically correct. Moreover, it's extremely common, especially in journalism, to use it this way.

Comment: So, is there no difference between "boast" and "boast of or about" in the context?

Comment: No, there *is* a difference. In this case it means "have or possess" as the dictionary definition states.